# Switch statement validation

Tags: php, validation

Does POST or GET data need to be validated if being thrown directly into a switch() statement? For example:

```
switch($_GET['input']) {
    //...
}
```

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your switch contains real cases no, but if you do `default` you need to validate the `$_GET` if you use it in that case.

eg:

```
switch ($_GET['input']) {
    case 'one':
        echo "input is one";
        break;
    case 'two':
        echo "input is two";
        break;
    default:
       // here `$_GET['input']` need to be validated, escaped, checked if you use it to avoid XSS or SQL injections
       echo $_GET['input'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, your `case` is basically the validation.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for.

Note that switch/case does loose comparision.

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case "apple":
        echo "i is apple";
        break;
    case "bar":
        echo "i is bar";
        break;
    case "cake":
        echo "i is cake";
        break;
    default:
    echo "";
    break;
}
?>
```

So, the short answer is "NO".